# Learn QM algebraic formulations and interpretations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, foundations

I have a good undergrad knowledge of quantum mechanics, and I'm interesting in reading up more about interpretation and in particular things related to how QM emerges algebraically from some reasonable real world assumptions. However I want to avoid the meticulous maths style and rather read something more meant for physicists (where rigorous proofs aren't needed and things are well-behaved ;) ) I.e. I'd prefer more intuitive resources as opposed to the rigorous texts.

Can you recommend some reading to get started?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An excellent book which does more or less what you ask for is Asher Peres' "[Quantum theory:concepts and methods](http://books.google.com/books/about/Quantum_theory.html?id=rMGqMyFBcL8C)". It starts from the Stern-Gerlach experiments and logical reasoning to develop the basic principles of quantum mechanics. From there, it develops the necessary algebra.

Another interesting book for an approach of the conceptual side of quantum mechanics is "[Quantum Paradoxes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3527403914)" by Aharonov and Rohrlich. But to fully appreciate this one, I think you will need  to go through a standard curriculum first.

Then, there is "[Quantum computation and Quantum Information](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521635039)" by Nielsen and Chuang, which is meant as an introduction to the ideas of QM as applied to information theory for people with an informatics background mostly. So it also starts from an algebraic and conceptual approach.

Comment: NB: Errata for the Aharonov/Rohrlich textbook can be found [here](http://www.wiley-vch.de/books/sample/3527403914_erratum.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Anthony Sudbery, Quantum Mechanics....
is an excellent text which emphasises the theory and interpretation
rather than the drill problems...in fact he is a mathematician and
quantum information theorist and this book is not so useful for 
someone who needs to bone up on their perturbation theory and 
get ready for QED, it focuses on what it sounds like you are 
especially interested in.

Answer (score 2):

For matrix mechanics (mixed with a bit of schrodinger), see the [NPTEL Lectures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcmGYe39XG0&list=PLE0334305C5C04C30).

For     path integrals, see Feynman, Hibbs (and Styer)    *Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals*.

Comment: +1 It's worth mentioning that the Feynman and Hibbs you refer to is the version "emended" by Styer and put into print since 2005 (as opposed to the original, which is out of print). See http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Mechanics-Path-Integrals-Emended/dp/0486477223 PS: I'd never seen "emend" in English before today!: the OED tells me that it is seldom used, it is the middle English root *emenden* of the more modern *amend* and, if used, always means *to amend a scholarly work* as opposed to simply change a general work. So it's Prof. Styer being pedantic!