# Good quantum physics textbooks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learn algebra and interpretation of QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14377/learn-algebra-and-interpretation-of-qm)

I'm a physics student it's my last year and I find my self struggling with usage of quantum mechanics. Now I'm starting to learn nuclear physics, solid state physics and soon quantum field theory and I see that I have holes in my knowledge. It's not that I'm completely ignorant, I've passed the exam in quantum physics I understand the concepts, but it doesn't feel right, I don't have the intuition like I do for example, classical mechanics or electrodynamics.
For example, of course, there are problems that I can't solve in classical mechanics or electrodynamics but I always know where to start I have an intuition about the problem and in most scenarios I have an ideas what solutions should look like. But in quantum physics, usually even for simple problems I can get stuck or don't know where to start. 
I want to rebuild my knowledge from a new source.
The literature I've used so far is:
[Introduction to Quantum Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131244051) by David J.Griffiths,
[Quantum physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070856435) by Leonard Schiff,
[Modern Quantum Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201539292) (Revised Edition) by J.J.Sakurai.

First one is an easy read, good introduction, but it doesn't use bra/ket notation.
Second on I just didn't like, it was hard to read, short on examples.
Third one I really like, but I'd like to see more examples and I can't check solutions for problems at the end of the chapters anywhere.

Could you please recommend me couple of more choices? I prefer books with lot of examples of solving problems. Also, while it's fine that book starts with wave functions, solving Schrodinger equations etc, I'd like a book that uses bra/ket notation.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky The link provided to claim a possible duplication has nothing to do with the question asked here. The question asked here is about books with solved problems on QM. Please provide a correct link if there is duplication otherwise it will not be fair to close this question.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have just checked ALL questions tagged books, and I find no similar question to the one asked here. I do not understand why the moderator closed that question!

Comment: This question is about QM textbooks. So is the other one. Officially these book recommendation questions are off topic anyway, but we've been able to allow a limited number of them by enforcing that the topics don't overlap. That is not the case with this question.

Comment: By the way, the links provided for Griffiths and Sakurai in the question are for old editions. There are newer editions of those 2 books.

Comment: Feynman, Hibbs & Styer' .(fgor the path integral formulation, of courese. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Schiff and Sakurai are graduate level books. A more "doable" textbook would be [Shankar's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0306447908).

Griffiths is the standard textbook for undergraduate QM. It is very nice book but, like most of QM textbooks, it must be supplemented by solved problems.

Your best choice is [Zettili's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470026790). It contains solved problems on all topics including bra-ket notation. That is the reason basically why it has such high rating on amazon. It bridged a needed gap in QM textbooks.

You can check also [Landau's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750635398). As far as I remember, it contains problems with insightful short answers spread throughout the book.

Comment: I went to library today and got the Zettili's book, that was EXACTLY what I was looking for, I wish I knew about this book earlier.

Comment: @enedene Great that I could help, make sure it is the 2nd edition. Knowing about it late is better than never.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you have more theoretical of experimental tendencies but i enjoyed a lot reading "Quantum mechanics" - Claude Cohen-Tannoudji. It is very precise but also more formal.

I think that, looking at how it is teached, quantum mechanics is a bit too academic. For something more interesting fromt the point of view of the examples you should try something of many-body theory but i understand that is a little out of the target.

Try also "Quantum mechanics" - Auletta Fortunato Parisi, Cambridge or "Quantum Mechanics" - Robinett, Oxford