# Studying Quantum mechanics from Schwinger's book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I'm gonna start studying some more advanced than introductory quantum mechanics. I partially studied Classical Electrodynamics from [Schwinger's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738200565) and I totally loved it, so I was thinking about going on with the same guy. Now After studying quantum mechanics from Griffiths I'd like something more advanced, is Schwinger's [Quantum kinematics and dynamics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738203033) a good way to continue the study of QM? I read the table of contents and it looks like it is a very complete book, but before buying and studying from it I'd like a comparison between the Schwinger and other more standard textbooks you may know. Some key questions you may answer are about stuff I cant't guess from the table of contents, for example:

- Is Schwinger out of date?
- Is it self contained?
- Is it "physical enough" while not lacking in formality?

But feel free to tell me any good features or defects of the book you may have encountered.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Disclaimer: I read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21100/), they don't mention Schwinger so I felt the need to ask another question. Since my question is mainly about Schwinger's book I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Well, they love it on amazon, 5 stars, and I can't see much difference between the buyers there and the user's here, for sure nobody else is going to buy it.

Comment: I'd be interested in books in similar style to QK&D on Relativistic Quantum Mechanics and on Quantum Field Theory. By "style" I mean (1) grounding in algebra and geometry (2) building up from a small number of axioms (3) coverage. QK&D is clear and complete. You don't have to guess at anything or reverse-engineer his mathematics. It's very short and easy to read (for me). It includes solutions to classical problems like Brownian motion. Anything like this for RQM or QFT? (I've read lots of much more difficult books)?

Comment: I think you should try to post a whole new question on the site to have more visibility. I just followed a 2 semester course on QFT and didn't start to study it deeply so I have no idea. I've read good things about Weinberg series and Matthew Schwarz book, but i have no experience on study on them.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post a "resource-recommendation" question. I cruised around the site looking at other such questions, and they tend to get closed, downvoted, changed to "community wiki," which I admit I do not understand. I think I understand why. My criteria are sufficiently vague and subjective that they will invite opinions rather than facts, and that seems to be the tipping point. A "bad" question seems to be one that invites opinions. I'll think about how to crisp up my criteria. Things like "readable" and "clear" are sure to incite disaster.

Comment: You could try to ask in the chat, maybe at different times in different days, in this way you'll have opinions of a lot of different people!