# Books on foundations of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

I am seeking for books on foundations of Quantum Mechanics with subjects like the EPR experiment, Bell's theorem, the problem of measurement, entanglement, decoherence, nonlocality, interpretations, QM without observer, different formalisms etc.

I prefer modern books, post graduate oriented, with history, formalisms and different approaches for a young researcher specialize himself on the subject.

EDIT: the other [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14377/2451) marked as "duplicate" do not fit my needs. I prefer books with higher modern mathematics, deep arguments and well-defined positions within the philosophy of science, post graduate oriented, if those exists. I need a book to get plenty knowledge as to do research in that academic area, not an intuitive approach.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22409/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I recommend "The interpretation of quantum mechanics" by R. Omnes at Princeton University Press. It starts with a regular introduction to Copenhagen quantum mechanics, and then all the foundational questions are discussed one by one, including decoherence. It includes exercises.