# A good textbook on Introduction to Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm starting my master in Physics. I've taken some Quantum classes before, but nothing as serious as this. I would like now to really go in detail with all the concepts of QM. My professor recommended us to buy Quantum Theory by David Bohm, but I think is a little bit hard for me. I'm looking for a textbook that explain the derivation of the mathematical formulas given. Some recommendations ?

Comment: Shankar and Griffiths are standard.

Comment: Besides the marked duplicate (I can only choose one), look at [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22409) and [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14377).